# XPath: What is the difference between dot = "Text" and dot comma "Text"

Tags: html, xpath

I'm trying to understand the difference between this XPath expression

```
'//button[contains(.,"My Text")]'
```

And this one:

```
'//button[.="My Text"]'
```

What is the impact when this `button` element has descendant text nodes with "My Text" string/substring?

Comment: `.` is recursive.

Comment: @Gilles Quénot No, it explains test() vs dot, not "=" vs ","

Comment: The difference is the first form is syntactically correct; the second form is not.  Beyond that, understand the key concepts in the two duplicate links to use `contains()` effectively.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to edited question:**

```
//button[contains(.,"My Text")]
```

This will select any `button` elements whose string value (I explain what string value means below) *contains* the value "My Text". That is, it will select those whose string value is "Have a look at My Text, please", and so on.

```
//button[.="My Text"]
```

This will select any button elements whose string value is exactly equal to "My Text".

**Answer to original question:**

The `contains` function accepts two arguments - the string being tested ("haystack") and the string being searched for ("needle"), in that order.

So

```
contains(., "My Text")
```

will be true if the string value of the current node (indicated by a dot) contains the value "My Text".

```
contains(.="My Text")
```

should produce an error because you are only passing one argument to it when it requires two.

But passing `.="My Text"` into it doesn't make any sense in the first place, since that expression will evaluate to either `true` or `false` depending on whether the current node's string value is exactly equal to "My Text", and then that `true` or `false` would be passed into the `contains` function.

> What is the impact when this button element has descendant text nodes with "My Text" string/substring?

The string value of an element is the concatenation of all text nodes within that element, in document order, including descendants multiple levels deep. So `contains(., "My Text")` would be true if that string value is present in any descendants and also if the concatenation of multiple descendant text nodes resulted in a string that contained "My Text"